# Plucker relations in G(3,6)

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, combinatorial-geometry, invariant-theory

Can someone please explicitly write down all the plucker relations for $G(3,6)$. I am having some trouble with the signs. What is the minimal number of relations needed to generate the Plucker ideal ?

Comment: See Chapter 14.2 of Miller and Sturmfels' Combinatorial Commutative Algebra: they discuss the minimal Plücker relations.

Comment: Of course, they also describe in detail the relations, so that book should answer your question.

Comment: In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/) try: `Grassmannian(2,5)`.